# Intellisense not working for Moq.Setup in VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, intellisense, moq

I am attempting to utilize Moq for my unit tests.  I added the library to the project and I created the mock object

```
        Mock _mock = new Mock<DocumentService>();
```

I am able to get intellisense for most methods off of the `Mock` object, such as `Mock.Object`, `Mock.ShouldBe<>`, etc...  However it does NOT show `Mock.Setup()`.

However, when I manually type out `_mock.Setup()` and I hold the cursor over the `Setup()` method and it shows the (what appears to be) correct signature.  Also, when I attempt to use lambda expressions inside of the `Setup()` method I don't get any intellisense.

So is there something I am missing to get this working?

Comment: Does the code compile when you call `Setup` with the correct parameters?

Comment: Nope, it says there is no definition for a method `Setup`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
Mock _mock = new Mock<DocumentService>();
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
Mock<DocumentService> _mock = new Mock<DocumentService>();
```

I'm sure there's a base class, but this would be in line with the sort of slicing off half the functionality you're seeing.

See, this is where lots of usage of `var` comes in!

Comment: wow, that's retarded of me.  Thanks (I'll mark this as the answer once I get home and see if that fixes it).

Comment: @KallDrexx: Dont worry, we've all been there!

Comment: Haha sometimes you just need a second pair of eyes to see the stupid mistakes.  That solved the issue, thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Another reason I came across for not seeing **Setup** method at all is that I some how I landed up using 2.x version of Moq.dll instead of 4.x. Make sure the version used in the project is 3.x or higher (4.x is better).